# MouseDragReleased calling MouseDragExited

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, javafx

I'm currently working on a battleship game. To support moving the ships in the start up, I tried to add a drag and drop feature. So, I want to have a ship on the field and I drag it and drop it on an empty field to move it.

```
public class DragDetectedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("drag detected");
        PlayingfieldField field = (PlayingfieldField) e.getSource();
        field.startFullDrag();
        e.consume();
    }
}

public class MouseDragEnteredHandler implements EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseDragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("drag entered");
        e.consume();
    }
}

public class MouseDragExitedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseDragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("drag exited");
        e.consume();
    }
}

public class MouseDragReleasedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseDragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("drag released"); 
        e.consume();

    }
}
```

Now, when I drag a ship to another field and drop it, I get the following output:

```
drag detected //Detected drag in start field
drag entered  //I drag in the start field, so the drag event enters
drag exited  //I exit the start field
drag entered  //I enter the second field
drag released //I release the mouse
drag exited  //???
```

So, as you see, after releasing the mouse, I always get the `drag exited` event. Does anbody know why, and how I can prevent this?

Comment: I could solve my problem by initalizing a boolean (dragAlreadyOver). In the MouseDragReleasedHandler I set it to 'true' and in the MouseDragExitedHandler I check if it is 'true'. If it is, I change it to 'false' and call 'return'. Otherwise I just continue with the handle method in MouseDragExitedHandler.
But I still don't really understand why MouseDragExitedHandler.handle is called after I released the mouse button (and MouseDragReleasedHandler.handle is called)... Should we report a bug to oracle or is this wanted? And if it is, why?